# how to open every new VS code window in a specific remote host?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like every new window of VScode to open using a specific remote host. In my case it's WSL but it could be any other registered one.

Is that possible and if yes how ?

Comment: Why are you asking two nearly identical questions so close together?

Comment: because in SO if I add ask these 2 questions at the same place I would have been strike for asking 2 questions at once. Maybe this can be useful for someone that don't need anything related to WSL

Comment: The answer to your first question will answer this question provided your first question is improved to a point where it can be answered

Comment: I'm sorry that you didn't understand my first question but it's really unrelated and I can clearly solve the first one without solving this one. The downvoted answer is a first step that put me on the right track making me think it is actually comprehensible